# How do I publish my DNS Server to the public so that my Domain Name will be accessible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, web

I recently setup a domain name server on my ubuntu machine and added my DNS record for my website, question is how to make my domain name accessible to the public without the public having to add my dns server on their machine's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this typically requires spending money at a DNS site, e.g. name.com, namecheap.com, GoDaddy (bad juju), etc..  Depending on the domain, you're going to probably spend at least $10/year.  Unfortunately this bureaucratic system (run somehow by ICANN) is a result of the government's role in shaping the internet.